# Dialog box opened from embedded view shows dialog box form instead of returning directly to embedded view

Tags: lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have an embedded view that opens a dialog box when clicking on the document in the view.
When closing the dialog box (using either a save and close or just close button useing basic @Commands), instead of the dialog box just closing it clears the underlying form from the screen and opens the dialog box as if it was a form.
If I close that, the original underlying form reappears which is what I want to happen without the intervening dialog box form appearing.

Is this because I am using @Function calls to `@Command([FileSave]); @Command([FileCloseWindow])` or is there something else I am missing? 
Is there a flag on the form that I am not setting or do the actions on the dialog box need to be written in LotusScript and they have to recall the form somehow?

The dialog box opens from the view using the following formula:

```
Sub Queryopendocument(Source As Notesuiview, Continue As Variant)
    Call OpenDocInDialogBox( Source, True, 1, "frmOrganization", "Organization") 
End Sub
```

and the OpenDocInDialogBox function is:

```
Function OpenDocInDialogBox( Source As NotesUIView, Continue As Variant, WhatIfNonEmbed As Integer, Form_Name As String, Dlg_Title As string) As Integer

    Dim DocColl As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim Doc As NotesDocument
    Dim flag As Integer
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim temp As Variant

    Continue = False
    flag = False

    Set DocColl = Source.Documents 
    Set Doc = DocColl.GetFirstDocument

    doc.IsDialogBox = "Yes"

    If Not ws.CurrentDocument Is Nothing Then 'Checks if it is an embedded view  
        If ws.CurrentDocument.EditMode Then   
            flag = ws.DialogBox( FORM_NAME, True, True, True  , False, False , False , DLG_TITLE, Doc , True, True )
        Else   
            flag = ws.DialogBox( FORM_NAME, True, True, True  , False, False , True , DLG_TITLE, Doc , True, True )   
        End If  
    Else  'open from an action button
        Select Case WhatIfNonEmbed   
        Case 0   
            MsgBox "Sorry.. You cannot open documents From the current view.", 0 + 16, "Warning"   
        Case 1              
            flag = ws.DialogBox( FORM_NAME, True, True, True, False, False , False, DLG_TITLE, Doc , True, True )   
        Case 2   
            doc.IsDialogBox = "No"
            Continue = True    
    End Select  
    End If

    OpenDocInDialogBox = flag

End Function
```

The flags in the code refer to the following

```
WhatIfNonEmbed tells how to open the document If gets opened From a non-embedded view.
WhatIfNonEmbed=0 ---- Dont Allow users To Open (meaning, doc can be only opened from the form In which it is embedded)
WhatIfNonEmbed=1 ---- Open In Dialog box.
WhatIfNonEmbed=2 ---- Normal Open using the form.
```

Comment: shouldn't ya call it with Call OpenDocInDialogBox( Source, Continue, 1, "frmOrganization", "Organization"), In your call the second parameter is true.. shouldn't that be 'Continue' instead...

Comment: Thank you - I never noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

umeli already answered in comments, but as he did not write a full answer, I will do that:

The QueryOpenDocument Event has a "Continue"- Variable that tells it, if the document should be "really" opened (Continue = True) or prohibited (Continue = False).

Dialogboxes are blocking. What your code does in the moment:

- it shows the Dialog during the QueryOpenDocument- Event and pauses that event until the dialogbox is closed.
- it does NOT set the continue- variable to "False": therefor after closing the dialog- box the "normal" process kicks in: your document is opened normally as new window.

Two possibilities to fix that:

1. Just as umeli said: Use the Variable "Continue" as parameter for your call instead of "True": As that one is set to "false" if dialog is shown (or back to true if parameter is like that) within that function and variables by default are passed by reference the underlying Continue- Variable will be changed and the QueryOpenDocument- process will be stopped.
   `Call OpenDocInDialogBox( Source, Continue, 1, "frmOrganization", "Organization")`
2. Set Continue = False yourself in the QueryOpenDocument event. Same effect, but then your complete WhatIfNonEmbed=2 - codepath does not do anything anymore.